# How to invoke an additional click and a drag when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Is it possible for a click or mouseup event to launch a function where an additional click and drag event is invoked on another part of the div or on another div?

In short when I click on something I want the mouseup event to create the equivalent of the user quickly selecting another div (or part of the same div) and dragging it. I am not looking for a css animation perse'.  I know that sounds weird but read below for what I think I need this for

**The problem I am trying to solve with this**

The problem I am trying to solve with this is the following.
I am making this tool:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57427474/JsPlumb_troubleshooting/trace3.html

When the user types into the pad, clicks the green button and moves the editor all works fine. But if they then again click the green button and add additional content to the notepad (and then closes the editor) the JSplumb wire-nodes get out of wack and don't update as in the picture below.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57427474/JsPlumb_troubleshooting/img.png

However, *when I drag the div the nodes fall back into place.*

**I was thinking if I could add an eventListener that slightly drags the div (using a mouse event) when the user clicks the green button I could subtly fix this.**

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `trigger();`

```
$("#myButton").trigger("click");
```

ymmv